# Reuse selector in other selectors in NGXS

Tags: ngxs

I have two classes PizzasState and ToppingsState.
PizzaState already has selector to get selected pizza.

```js
@State<PizzaStateModel>({
  name: 'pizzas',
  defaults: initialState
})
export class PizzasState {
  constructor(private pizzaService: PizzasService) {
  }

  @Selector([RouterState])
  static getSelectedPizza(
    state: PizzaStateModel,
    routerState: RouterStateModel<RouterStateParams>
  ): Pizza {
    const pizzaId = routerState.state && routerState.state.params.pizzaId;
    return pizzaId && state.entities[pizzaId];
  }

  @Selector()
  getPizzaVisualized(state: PizzaStateModel): Pizza {
    //
    // what is here?
    //
  }
}
```

and ToppingsState has selectedToppings

```js
@State({
  name: 'toppings',
  defaults: initialState
})
export class ToppingsState {
  constructor(private toppingsService: ToppingsService) {
  }

  @Selector()
  static selectedToppings(state: ToppingsStateModel): number[] {
    return state.selectedToppings;
  }
```

Now I want to join my selected pizza with selected toppings and get my visualized pizza.

How can I reuse getSelectedPizza and getSelectedToppings correctly?
Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like you need to use a [joining selector](https://ngxs.gitbook.io/ngxs/concepts/select#joining-selectors).

```
@Selector([ToppingsState.selectedToppings])
getPizzaVisualized(state: PizzaStateModel, selectedToppings: number[]): Pizza {
    // User data from both states.
}
```

Comment: thanks, but how can I reuse my getSelectedPizza selector? Do I have to write this logic again here? Really?

Comment: There is createSelector function in NGRX, which solve this issue

Comment: You can pass the selector itself if you want to .. I'll edit to show this .. although in this case, to just access a single property on state it might not be worth adding a selector.
This updated syntax should be ok, I tested it on some states I'm working with.

Comment: Now, I undestand how it works. Thank you very much. Should add an example to the documentation